# What are pipe and tap methods in Angular tutorial?

Tags: angular

I'm following the tutorial at https://angular.io, and I'm having trouble finding documentation; specifically for the methods `pipe` and `tap`.  I can't find anything on https://angular.io or http://reactivex.io/rxjs/.

My understanding is that `pipe` and `tap` are both methods of `Observable`, which is being imported from RxJS, correct? What are they supposed to do?

Are these methods part of Angular? What do these two methods do?

Comment: I find it strange when users ask proper questions, receive a proper answer, and yet for the mods are clueless what OP is asking :D - why the hell is this "off-topic"?

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You are right, the documentation lacks of those methods. However when I dug into rxjs repository, I found nice comments about [tap](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.2/src/operators/tap.ts#L14) (too long to paste here) and [pipe](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.2/src/Observable.ts#L306) operators:

```
  /**
   * Used to stitch together functional operators into a chain.
   * @method pipe
   * @return {Observable} the Observable result of all of the operators having
   * been called in the order they were passed in.
   *
   * @example
   *
   * import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
   *
   * Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
   *   .pipe(
   *     filter(x => x % 2 === 0),
   *     map(x => x + x),
   *     scan((acc, x) => acc + x)
   *   )
   *   .subscribe(x => console.log(x))
   */
```

### In brief:

**Pipe**: Used to stitch together functional operators into a chain. Before we could just do `observable.filter().map().scan()`, but since every RxJS operator is a standalone function rather than an Observable's method, we need `pipe()` to make a chain of those operators (see example above).

**Tap**: Can perform side effects with observed data but **does not modify** the stream in any way. Formerly called `do()`. You can think of it as if observable was an array over time, then `tap()` would be an equivalent to `Array.forEach()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the links.  Part of my problem is that I'm new to Angular, and I'm not sure which methods are part of core JavaScript or Node.js or RxJS or Angular.  Your answer helped me to clarify that. Thank you.

Comment: @BenRubin I would recommend that you start by learning native JS properly before starting to learn the tools. It will make it much easier to understand the tools and what it actually does (and to know what parts is native vs the tool).

Comment: since 5.5 and the introduction of pipeable (once known as lettable) operators, `do` as been renamed as `tap`... In short, it's a mess. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: Can you explain me with an example what every line (filter, map, scan) exactly do?

Comment: `filter` works just like `Array.filter` - keeps only values fulfilling the rule (in this case divisible by 2); `map` (again like `Array.map`) changes every value (in this case adds it to itself); `scan` is most interesting and here is a nice explanation: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html

Comment: looks like scan is reduce

Comment: would be more helpful if you could explain these in addition to providing the docs - thanks for those though.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm in the same situation, sometimes just don't know what to type. Can you recommend a site learning native JS?

Comment: @Jeb50 - Try searching google for something like "get started with javascript" and you should get a bunch of suggestions.