# Manipulate Observable<Hero[]>

Tags: angular

Let's take for example the following hero code to get heroes:

```
/** GET heroes from the server */
  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(heroes => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
        catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
      );
  }
```

I want to manipulate each element of hero[]. I tried .map function:

```
  getHeroes (): Observable<Hero[]> {
            return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
              .pipe(
                tap(heroes => this.log(`fetched heroes`)),
                catchError(this.handleError('getHeroes', []))
              ).map((result) => {
                 console.log(result); // I am getting all the array and not iteration.
                 return  Object.assign(new Hero(), result);
             );
          }
```

but I am getting all the array or Hero[] and its not iterate the heroes one by one.

Comment: put the "map" before the "tap", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275385/what-are-pipe-and-tap-methods-in-angular-tutorial

Comment: You need to call Array.map() on the emitted array, not on the observable. BTW, you should really not mix pipeable operators and old, instance operators. Stick to pipeable operators.

Comment: map(result=>{return result.map(x=>Object.assign(new Hero(),x)})

Answer (score 2):

`Map` manipulates the `Observable` data which you get at the moment, not each data inside it. And because you get your heroes in the array, not one by one, you get the whole array inside `map` as a single data.

You need to use `Array.map` on the result, create your mapped array and pass it to the next.

*RxJS 5* now uses `do` instead of the `tap`.

Comment: is there an option to get the Hero one by one and not as an array? Can you please share a small example how to use the Array.map?

Comment: You don't need to get one by one. So that you get your array from the server, you can just manipulate it via `map` function like

`return  result.map(item => Object.assign(new Hero(), item)) ` or just cast your array to `result as Hero[]`

Comment: `array or Hero`?

Comment: Suren Srapyan - I tried rxJS map function - result.map(item => Object.assign(new Hero(), item)) and its not working because the item is an array **of** Hero and not single Hero. how can i cast the array to result as Hero[]?