# Angular HttpClient combine pipe, tap with subscribe?

Tags: angular, publish-subscribe, angular-httpclient

I am trying to retrieve some data with HttpClient in Angular. My code looks like as follows:

```
getData(suffurl: string, id?:number): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('localhost:5555/DNZ/'+ this.suff_url)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log("Anlagenstatus Daten:", data)),
      catchError(this.handleError('getData',[])),
      subscribe(Response => { console.log(Response)})
    )
  }
```

However, I cannot use subscribe in the pipe method, or chain it before or after the .pipe method. The problem is, that without subscribe, it seems this code is not returning any data from the url or logging anything to the console although the link and the data exists?

Comment: The service should NOT subscribe. The **caller** of this service  should. https://angular.io/guide/http And why, oh why are you using `any`? Wouldn't it be nice to know what the array actually contains?

Comment: actually, I have this "service" in my component as a method, so the  caller is actually the one who subscribes... but I did it now in NgOnInit()...

Comment: Well, don't do that. Put your data access code in a service. https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: +1 Always bubble up the asynchronicity to the caller as far as you can and use it there!
_Off-topic: Oh dear, it seems every time I answer one of these `async` `Promise` `Observable` or `http.request` questions another pops up. Staunch the bleeding! Bail out!_

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must subscribe to the method (since it returns an `Observable`), not inside the pipe.

Try this instead

```
getData(suffurl: string, id?:number): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('localhost:5555/DNZ/'+ this.suff_url)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log("Anlagenstatus Daten:", data)),
      catchError(this.handleError('getData',[])),
    )
  }
```

then make a call

```
this.getData("url").subscribe(Response => { console.log(Response)})
```

Comment: ok thanks, this solved my problem, now I have the data in the Response, what would I do now when I wanted to do data processing with e.g. .map() functions? can I chain the function map anywhere before or after subscribe? And secondly, why can't I subscribe directly after the method, this was the case with the old Http library, you used it by doing a get query followed by a .subscribe method... I was just wondering why they did it different this time with the new HttpClient..?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can use map inside the pipe like this: `.pipe(
      map(data => { return doSomeLogic;}))`. Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275385/what-are-pipe-and-tap-methods-in-angular-tutorial I am not sure I understand the second question about subscribing directly. You can subscribe directly in your getData()-function, by using .pipe().subscribe(). However, you will then return a `Subscription`, not an `Observable`. Hope that helps