# Angular - Using a service property set by callback in another component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, promise

I am trying to use a `DataService` property `myData` that is waiting for callback. But it is undefined when I call in `DataComponent`. How can I access and use it there?

```
export class DataService {
  public myData;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.load().then((data) => {
      this.myData = data
    })
  }

  load() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.http.get('https://reqres.in/api/users').subscribe(
        (res: any) => {
          console.log(res.data)
          resolve(res.data)
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
    })
  }
}
```

```
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.prepareData();
  }

  prepareData() {
    console.log(this.dataService.myData)
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Here is the source code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kbpdpo

Comment: You should use Observable in service and subscribe in dataComponent ex. in ngOnInit lifecycle hook.

Comment: The issue is because this is asynchronus, your data is not loaded yet by the time your component loaded. You can test this by adding `setTimeout()` on `prepareData()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are pipe and tap methods in Angular tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275385/what-are-pipe-and-tap-methods-in-angular-tutorial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a race condition since this is an asynchronous function.

This change works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vf3llg

Consider reading up on https://angular.io/guide/http

Personally, I just have services return raw data and manipulate it elsewhere, but if needed you can tap into the response as I have shown i the updated example.

This question and answer are probably really a duplicate of this question...

[What are pipe and tap methods in Angular tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275385/what-are-pipe-and-tap-methods-in-angular-tutorial)

Comment: I would like to get the data and modify it in the DataService and use this modified version in another components. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. But every time I call `load` function and subscribe to it, it is calling HTTP get function again. Isn't there any way to call HTTP get method only once and modify the data and use this modified data in other components?

Comment: Yes, there is. What have you tried so far? It looks like what is missing from your question is in the HTML where you plan to consume/display this data. For example you could achieve this with an async pipe.

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Answer (score 0):

your `load()` method is asynchronous, that means that it can return the response after 2 hours, so it will execute your callback after 2 hours, and you are asking  `myData` synchronously which means that you are asking it right now, so it won't work.

you have to wait until the answer is returned, in your code there is no chance to accomplish this, so either remove yourData field and just subscribe it into the component, or create `BehaviorSubject` and emit value to the component