# How to emit observable upon receiving data from frokJoin subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

So basically I want to get data from 3 observables with forkJoin and once they emit values I want to emit another observable form subscription logic, so I can subscribe to it from another place. What I have now

```
 getOptionsArray = <T>(): Observable<any> => {
    forkJoin([
      get1(),
      get2(),
      get3()
    ]).subscribe(([data1, data2, data3]) => {
      // some necessary assignment logic which needs to be here...

      // here I want to emit observable so I can subscribe to getOptionsArray method from 
      // another place, but only after logic in subcription here is applied.
    })
}
```

I know I could just return **forkJoin** and just subscribe to it from another place, but I need to do some assignment logic first inside this function and then once this logic is applied I want to return observable from this method to which I could subscribe from another place.

Comment: I think you can use pipe() or tap() for that, depending on whether you want to modify the stream or just perform a side effect. You can look here to see the difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47275385/what-are-pipe-and-tap-methods-in-angular-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options:

```
getOptionsArray = <T>(): Observable<any> => {
    return forkJoin([
      get1(),
      get2(),
      get3()
    ]).pipe(map([data1, data2, data3]) => {
        ...
        return result;
    }))
}
```

or

```
getOptionsArray = <T>(): Observable<any> => {
    let subject = new Subject();
    forkJoin([
      get1(),
      get2(),
      get3()
    ]).subscribe(([data1, data2, data3]) => {
        ...
        subject.next(result);
        subject.completes();
    });
    return subject.asObservable();
}
```

I prefer the first one.